# Redirecting HTTP requests to device without static/public IP

Tags: python, sockets, redirect, ssh-tunnel

I'm using a service that sends me some data from user over webhooks. If there is any user interaction on this service, it hits my URL with HTTP request, with the data in POST/GET, and then expects text/json response to show back to the user. The response has to be in few seconds, otherwise the HTTP request times out and the service has no way of finding out what should be the response to the user. 
The problem here is that now I'm not processing these data on my server with public IP, but I need to do it on my RPi, which keeps moving, which meains it has different IP every few hours, and mostly not public.

I'm sure I will still need to use the server with public IP to redirect these requests to my RPi, and I have few ideas, but I don't know what is reliable or if it even would work.

1. Let the API talk to my server and save the data. Then have the RPi constantly asking my server if there are any new data. Propably the dumbest idea - not ideal to use over metered connection, propably longer reply, and it will be harder to return the RPi's reply in the HTTP request made from API.
2. Having (Python) script running on my server, that will a) serve as socket server and RPi will connect to this socket, and b) have running SimpleHTTPRequestHandler to process requests from API and send them to the socket, the reply with RPi's reply. Propably easy way to keep connection between my server and RPi, allowing me to pass data in both directions.
3. Open SSH tunnel between the RPi and my server. This way, I could process the requests from service directly on my RPi. But how reliable is this solution? (Keeping it alive, opening the tunnel automatically, etc, propably question for superuser forum)

I'm thinking of going with choice 3 if it will be possible, but first I'd like to hear what you guys think. Is this a good and reliable idea? Or are there any better ways I don't know about? Or did anybody already faced this problem?

To sum it up:
Something sends HTTP request to public IP. I need to process this request (and reply to it) in Python script on device without public IP. I have a server with public IP that could be used as a bridge. I much don't care what will run on the server, if it will be able to redirect these requests. 
Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use a [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service, where your RPi updates the associated ip regularly, and your webserver always proxies to the DNS name.

Comment: As I said, the RPi will have "different IP every few hours, and **mostly not public**", so dynamic DNS will not always work

Comment: Apologies - I missed that. You probably want to look at a variant of 3, using [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) possibly wrapped by systemd to ensure it stays active on ip address change etc.